# How to get a +15v&-15v DC from variable AC source using Full-wave rectifier?

Tags: voltage, rectifier, zener, electricity, full-bridge

How to get to *DC voltages* **(+15v & -15v)** by using *Full-wave rectifier*, and if I **change** the AC source, the output stay **stable**, i.e Independent on AC source...
any help?

.....
I want to change AC voltages (like 220v or 110v ...) with 80% efficiency and I want 2 outputs, first one is +15v, and the second is -15v, I want a stable voltage at output. I need a figure of circuit :) Thanks for effort.

Comment: Are you looking for a circuit or a product recommendation? Also it's a bit vague when you talk about changing the AC source - can you be more specific?

Comment: "and if I change the AC source" - change it to what exactly?

Comment: I want to change AC voltages (like 220v or 110v ...) and I want 2 outputs, first one is +15v, and the second is -15v, I want a stable voltage at output.
I need a figure of circuit :)
Thanks for effort

Comment: never ask this type of question without specifying min:max range power , efficiency, cost qty and tolerances.. if you don't know how to get it approved, buy it. and then learn how it is done before you try.

Comment: OK, My range from 110 to 220 AC volt,
80% efficiency,
I don't care about cost, no importance for this.

Comment: Let me repeat an important sentence from Tony's comment: **then learn how it is done** this means that **you** will have to look at some designs and decide which one will fit your needs or comes closest and if needed what changes you need to make. You seem to expect **us** to de all that for you. Well that's not going to happen !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you seem to expect us to come up with a design for you without you spending any effort to find one yourself. This is not a design service !

Comment: In your specific case, really, the easiest is to buy a standard SMPS. [There you go](http://www.mouser.fr/Power/Power-Supplies/Switching-Power-Supplies/_/N-axgkh?P=1yxt7erZ1yxt78xZ1yxt7cyZ1yxt74m). You're welcome. Now, voting to close as well.

Comment: Please, wait...
I worked on many values virtually in Full-wave rectifier (bridge) (on multisim) and I fail to make the output stable, I want to implement this on a breadboard, I can't buy it now.

Comment: @MeqdadDarweesh If you worked on a design, you should show it, then.

Comment: This is my rectifier,

[link](https://s12.postimg.org/n8287e8pp/Capture.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

How about one of these: -

[image]

This came from a company called Premier Magnetics and they have published many, many SMPS designs and will even sell you the transformer.

[Here's](http://www.premiermag.com/html/product-family/power-magnetics.html) their site and specifically it takes you to designs using Power Integration chips, Texas Instruments and Fairchild.

Scout around the hundreds of designs and pick one else, go and buy a standard one and attach DC to DC converters to the output to get what you want in terms of voltage and current.

Comment: Appropriate answer, I think, for such a question. Better than deserved and I'm sure it's way over the OP's head, but entirely appropriate. It at least lets them know just what they are asking for. (They didn't even specify current compliance, I now see. I'm going to vote to close.)

Comment: Nice xfmr source. Tks.

Comment: @spehro always a pleasure.